# Spark (Yarn) applications started by Zeppelin in Yarn Cluster Mode aren't killed after zeppein is stopped

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I'm running Zeppelin 0.8.1 and have configured it to submit Spark jobs to a Yarn 2.7.5 cluster, with interpreters both in cluster-mode (as in the AM is running on yarn, and not on driver host), and in client-mode.

The yarn applications started in client mode are immediately killed after I stop the Zeppelin server. But, the jobs started in cluster mode become zombie-like, and start hogging all the resources in the Yarn cluster (No dynamic resource allocation).

Is there a way to make zeppelin kill those jobs upon exit? Or anything that solves this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version 0.8, Zeppelin provides a parameter to shutdown idle interpreters by setting `zeppelin.interpreter.lifecyclemanager.timeout.threshold`.

See [Interpreter Lifecycle Management](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/interpreter/overview.html#interpreter-lifecycle-management)

Before this I used a simple shell script that checks the running applications on yarn and kills them if idle for more than 1 hour:

```sh
max_life_in_mins=60

zeppelinApps=`yarn application -list 2>/dev/null | grep "RUNNING" | grep "Zeppelin Spark Interpreter" | awk '{print $1}'`

for jobId in $zeppelinApps
do
    finish_time=`yarn application -status $jobId 2>/dev/null | grep "Finish-Time" | awk '{print $NF}'`
    if [ $finish_time -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "App $jobId is not running"
      exit 1
    fi

    time_diff=`date +%s`-`yarn application -status $jobId 2>/dev/null | grep "Start-Time" | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's!$!/1000!'`
    time_diff_in_mins=`echo "("$time_diff")/60" | bc`

    if [ $time_diff_in_mins -gt $max_life_in_mins ]; then
      echo "Killing app $jobId"
      yarn application -kill $jobId
    fi
done
```

There is also yarn [REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API) to do the same thing.

Comment: The thing is, the doc says the default timeout is 1 hour. but we've had interpreters run for days... anyhow, I'll try it. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I tried it and it worked! thanks :)

I don't understand why we had so many OLD interpreters running before tho...

There's a caveat with this solution: on client-mode applications, it stops the interpreter and the application state changes to `FINEISHED`; but in cluster-mode it stops the driver and the interpreter, which in turn makes the AM try to reconnect to the driver, creating a new `attempt`. which, in turn, gets a connection refused, and results in the application state changing to `FAILED`.
So, this messes the logs up, albeit solving the problem.